# Error to make libfacerec-0.04

Tags: make

I'm trying to compile the   libfacerec-0.04 for Face Recognition
from here https://github.com/bytefish/libfacerec/zipball/v0.04
and i follow this site for face recognition https://thinkrpi.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/step-3-install-softwares-for-webcam-and-computer-vision/ 
when i unzip and try to compile the API  libfacerec-0.04 using

```
sudo cmake .

sudo make
```

Then this error occuring :

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/bytefish-libfacerec-e1b143d $ sudo make
[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/opencv_facerec.dir/src/lbp.cpp.o
/home/pi/bytefish-libfacerec-e1b143d/src/lbp.cpp: In function ‘void cv::elbp_(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int)’:
/home/pi/bytefish-libfacerec-e1b143d/src/lbp.cpp:155:110: error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
/home/pi/bytefish-libfacerec-e1b143d/src/lbp.cpp:155:130: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
/home/pi/bytefish-libfacerec-e1b143d/src/lbp.cpp:155:130: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘float’
/home/pi/bytefish-libfacerec-e1b143d/src/lbp.cpp:155:154: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
CMakeFiles/opencv_facerec.dir/build.make:123: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/opencv_facerec.dir/src/lbp.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/opencv_facerec.dir/src/lbp.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/opencv_facerec.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/opencv_facerec.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have the CMakeLists.txt file updated, with correct values into.
e.g. line 7 should be manually set.

Comment: are there any other values that need to checked/change?